# Question about difference between "nut" and "eccentric" and "crazy" while talking to natives

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I know they all refer to unusual behaviour in a person.  But in modern life while you work and you meet a native speaker of English in America and then there is a conversation what do the words really mean?

Comment: Any of those terms can be totally benign if said while smiling and laughing. Psychopath, narcissist and sociopath can't be said so lightly.

Answer (score 1):

In order of severity, from greatest to least:

### 1. Nut

> This can be *very* insulting and is only used `informally`. Similar to: nutcase, nut job, loony, etc.
>
> There is, however, a non-insulting use: It can also mean `very enthusuastic about something` like a hobby or interest as in *sports nut*. Meaning: a person who loves sports a lot.

### 2. Crazy

> Although less informal than the first one, the two terms are fairly the same. However, you may hear it used lightly to express surprise or disbelief like  in this scenario:
>
> > Jesse: "I broke up with James last night."
> >
> > Meowth: "That's crazy."

### 3. Eccentric

> It can mean:
>
> > 1. `slightly strange` or just `weird` as in *eccentric taste*
> > 2. `unconventional` as in *eccentric billionaire*
>
> Although, this may be used as a [euphemism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) for the first two terms.

Comment: I'm not inclined to downvote, but I disagree. To me (an American) the terms are fairly equivalent and usually used in a "harmless" kind of way.

Comment: @Jolenealaska That's why I included the "harmless" uses. The differences are subtle: To me 1 and 2 may be interchangeable, but I can't say the same for 3.

Comment: Even after that exchange, I think we fundamentally disagree. You refer to the word "nut" as insulting, even *very* insulting. Even in a context that excludes the use that means "fan", I'm not seeing the term as being particularly insulting. As a matter of fact, I've more often used it as a way to be kind of complimentary.

Comment: @Jolenealaska In an attempt to highlight the _nuance_ of each word, my answer may appear to exaggerate the difference.  Also, I already pointed out that the "sports nut" usage is non-insulting, so I think you may have misread or I just wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Jolenealaska as a fellow American I would have to disagree. I think Helix Quar answered it perfectly and personally I find being called nuts far more insulting then being called crazy

Answer (score 1):

From American Heritage Dictionary -

> Nut (slang) - a crazy **or** an eccentric person

This would indicate that the terms *nutty, crazy* and *eccentric* may be interchangeable in some contexts.

Now my opinion (sorry, not a native though!).

When you call someone 'crazy', it adds a bit of danger there *(Don't go near him, he's crazy, he can beat up you)*; *nut* is more kind of a fool, funny looking OR (at times innocent? -I remember Mary Jane calling *you are such a nut* to Peter Parker); *eccentric* is a person with *odd or unusual personality*.

Comment: @J.R. _eccentric_ is noun as well and it's plural is eccentrics

Comment: Very true, good point – it can be used that way. More often than not, though, you'll see it used as an adjective (interesting [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eccentric_NOUN%2Ceccentric_ADJ%2Cnut_NOUN%2Ceccentrics&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)).